# \linesnumbered in package algorithm2e: how to change font size of numbers indicating the lines?

Tags: algorithm2e, line-numbering

I'm using algorithm2e package \linesnumbered in Overleaf, but font size of numbers indicating the lines in the algorithm is smaller than I expected. Is there any way to change the font size?

Answer (score 1):

The `algorithm2e` package provides the command `\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize` to control the font size of the line numbers. This is described in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) on page 25. Note that there is a mistake in the manual: the command is listed as `\SetAlgoNLRelativeSize` with capital letter `L`, but the correct command (as seen in the example code further down in the manual) is `\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize` with lower case `l`.

The size provided is relative to the font size of the algorithm itself. The default size is -2, so the first option that is bigger is -1.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \eIf {\( x>y \)}{greater}{less than or equal}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize{-1}
\begin{algorithm}
  \eIf {\( x>y \)}{greater}{less than or equal}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize{0}
\begin{algorithm}
  \eIf {\( x>y \)}{greater}{less than or equal}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize{1}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \eIf {\( x>y \)}{greater}{less than or equal}
\end{algorithm}

\SetAlgoNlRelativeSize{2}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \eIf {\( x>y \)}{greater}{less than or equal}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the MWE contains the `[H]` specifier for the last two algorithms (`\begin{algorithm}[H]`), this is just to keep the algorithms on one page for the example. In real code you should try to avoid the `[H]` specifier to prevent uneven layout of the pages.

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect!
I just solved my problem with \SetNlSty{textbf}{\footnotesize}{}, but your answer provides a better solution.